# No network in VirtualBox Guest (Ubuntu) after resuming from Sleep on Windows 10 host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

**SETUP**

Using VirtualBox 6.1.28, Windows 10 (host), Ubuntu 18.04 (Guest).

**DETAILS**

I launch the Ubuntu 18.04 Guest in VirtualBox and verify everything working normally.  I put the Windows 10 host into sleep mode.  I resume from sleep after a few minutes.  Now, the Ubuntu guest has lost its network (cannot access internet and all ping requests returns failure).

After some playing around I found that I could get the Ubuntu guest network back online by selecting (on the VirtualBox menu bar) Machine | Settings | Network ... and then select "NAT" and pressing Okay.  Then again select Machine | Settings | Network ... and reselect "Bridged Adapter" and pressing Okay.

But I don't want to open the VirtualBox Settings dialog twice each time I resume the Host PC and click options so I tried to script this using:

```
VBoxManage.exe controlvm <MyVM> nic1 nat
VBoxManage.exe controlvm <MyVM> nic1 bridged eth0
```

Unfortunately, this does not completely work on its own.  In order to get these calls to VBoxManage.exe to work I still need to open VirtualBox and select Machine | Settings | Network ... but I do not have to change the "Attached To" settings as I did above ... I simply have to click the Okay button.  After that the Ubuntu guest network comes online again.

**QUESTIONS:**

Any ideas on how I can simulate the press of the Okay button in the VirtualBox Settings/Network dialog so my CLI call to VBoxManage.exe will re-activate the network?

Any ideas why pressing the Okay button in the VirtualBox GUI appears to "flush/complete" the request I make on the CLI using VBoxManage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I get similar issues on a machine that's entirely Ubuntu. It's a quick and dumb fix, but try disconnecting your network or network adapter from inside the Ubuntu guest OS. Nothing that you've said is hinting to me that the Ubuntu VM is disconnecting from the Windows bits, so the issue could be entirely in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the idea J. Mini.  I just tried it but unfortunately, it didn't work.  I tried using `nmcli con down 'Wired connection 1'` followed by `nmcli con up 'Wired connection 1'` but that did not restore network connectivity within the Ubuntu guest.